# Multiple Page BeautifulSoup Script only Pulling first value

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

New to screen scraping here and this is my first time posting on stackoverflow. Aplogies in advance for any formatting errors in this post.   Attempting to extract data from multiple pages with URL: 
 https://www.landwatch.com/Michigan_land_for_sale/West_Central_Region/Page-' + str(page)

For instance, page 1 is:

https://www.landwatch.com/Michigan_land_for_sale/West_Central_Region/Page-1

Page 2: 
https://www.landwatch.com/Michigan_land_for_sale/West_Central_Region/Page-2

and so on...

My script is running without errors.  However, my Pandas exported csv only contains 1 row with the first extracted value. At the time of this posting, the first value is:

14.01 Acres Â  Vestaburg, Montcalm County, MI$275,000

My intent is to create a spreadsheet with hundreds of rows that pull the property description from the URLs.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from requests import get

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'
            }
           )
n_pages = 0
desc = []
for page in range(1,900):
    n_pages += 1
    sapo_url = 'https://www.landwatch.com/Michigan_land_for_sale/West_Central_Region/Page-' + str(page)
    r=get(sapo_url, headers=headers)
    page_html = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    house_containers = page_html.find_all('div', class_="propName")
    if house_containers != []:
        for container in house_containers:
            desc = container.getText(strip=True)
    else:
        break

print('you scraped {} pages containing {} Properties'.format(n_pages, len(desc)))



import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'description': [desc]}) 
df.to_csv('test4.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

I suspect the problem is with the line reading *desc = container.getText(strip=True)* and have tried changing the line but keep getting errors when running.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the mistake is in the line:

```
desc = container.getText(strip=True)
```

Every time it loops, the value in `desc` is replaced, not added on. To add items into the list, do:

```
desc.append(container.getText(strip=True))
```

Also, since it is already a list, you can remove the brackets from the DataFrame creation like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'description': desc})
```

Comment: This worked great!  Thank you for your feedback.  Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem! If you don’t mind, could you select my answer as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that no data is being added in the loop, so only the final data is being saved. For testing purposes, this code is now on page 2, so please fix it.

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'
            }
           )
n_pages = 0
desc = []
all_data = pd.DataFrame(index=[], columns=['description'])

for page in range(1,3):
    n_pages += 1
    sapo_url = 'https://www.landwatch.com/Michigan_land_for_sale/West_Central_Region/Page-' + str(page)
    r=get(sapo_url, headers=headers)
    page_html = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    house_containers = page_html.find_all('div', class_="propName")
    if house_containers != []:
        for container in house_containers:
            desc = container.getText(strip=True)
            df = pd.DataFrame({'description': [desc]})
            all_data = pd.concat([all_data, df], ignore_index=True)
    else:
        break

all_data.to_csv('test4.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
print('you scraped {} pages containing {} Properties'.format(n_pages, len(desc)))
```

Comment: Really appreciate your response. With this code I am still getting only one line result.  The other commented solution worked out well.  Issue being that code is replacing instead of appending to the dataframe with each loop.

Comment: I checked the CSV file output from your comment and it is indeed a single line. The code of `all_data` is modified because the intended result is obtained. `df.to_csv`->`all_data.to_csv` is the modified content.